# Remove Specific div from the same class group using jquery

Tags: jquery

Below the the HTML that i'm using to create on the elements page.

```
<div class="Att-Table">
                        <div class="FileRow">
                             <div class="Cell">
                                <span><input id="browse" type="file"/></span>
                            </div>
                            <div class="Cell">
                                <span><input placeholder="Description" id="desc" type="text"/></span>
                            </div>
                            <div class="Cell">
                                <span><a id="img1" href="#"><img class="delete" src="img/delete.png" /></a></span>
                            </div>
                        </div>
<div>
```

My requirement was to clone the below div every time 'Add Another' button is clicked.

```
<span>Add Another<a href="#" id="FileAdd"><img src="img/add.png" class="add" /></a></span>
```

Once the button is click i call a clone js which is something like shown below

```
$("#FileAdd").click(function() {
    var newElement = $(document.createElement('div')).attr({
        class: "FileRow"
    });
    newElement.html('<div class="Cell">\
                        <span><input id="browse" type="file"/></span>\
                    </div>\
                    <div class="Cell">\
                        <span><input placeholder="Description" id="desc" type="text"/></span>\
                    </div>\
                    <div class="Cell">\
                        <span><a id="img1" onclick="FileAdd" href="#"><img class="delete" src="img/delete.png" /></a></span>\
                    </div>');
    newElement.appendTo(".Att-Table");
});
```

I have a div with class "FileRow" to group these newly created elements. Now my requirement is to delete one specific div from that cloned group. I'm new to Jquery and would be helpful if somebody can help me out with it.

Comment: `delete one specific element from that cloned group`  what is that element..?

Comment: (1) *"...requirement is to delete one specific element.."*: which one? how do you identify that *specific* element? (2) you are duplicating your ids by cloning.

Comment: ...and how element should be removed? Do you want 'remove' button beside every field?

Comment: Basically every time i clone, A new div with the same class name "FileRow" is created with several elements inside of it. There is a delete button as well. I need to remove that div on the click of that delete button.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So first you can replace `document.createElement('div')` by `"<div/>"` this will produce the exact same thing.

Secondly it's quiet simple. Because you know the dom structure you can simply bind a click handler to your delete button and ask to remove from the dom the parent of the parent of the clicked element.

Which give us something like this for your fileAdd function which should probably be renamed because a `delete` action called `add` is a bit weird:

```
function fileAdd() {
    $(this).parent().parent().remove();
}
```

Comment: Thank you for the solution i was able to handle it :), also the first tip was really helpful

Answer (score 0):

### this works.

```
<script type="text/javascript">
window.jQuery(document).ready(function(){
    window.jQuery('.delete').on('click',function(){
        window.jQuery(this).closest('.FileRow').remove();
    });
});
</script>
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to use event delegation for binding the event to dynamically added DOM:

```
 $('body').on('click','.delete',function(){
    $(this).closest('.FileRow').remove();
 });
```